# Pass arguments to interactive shell in Docker Container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

Currently I'm trying to create a Docker image for jitsi-meet.
I installed `jitsi-meet` on my test system and noticed, that I get prompted for user input. Well, this is absolutely fine, when installing jitsi manually.

However the installation process is supposed to run during the build of the image. Which means there is no way for me to manually type in the necessary data.

Is there any way to pass values as an environment variable in the Dockerfile and use the variable in the container when I get prompted to enter some additional information?

This is how my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM debian:latest

WORKDIR /opt/jitsi-meet

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y ssh sudo ufw apt-utils apt-transport-https wget gnupg2 && \
    wget -qO - https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi-key.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add - && \
    sh -c "echo 'deb https://download.jitsi.org stable/' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jitsi-stable.list" && \
    apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install jitsi-meet

EXPOSE 80 443
EXPOSE 10000/udp
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can can set ENV vars in a docker file

using 'ENV', see:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement

To use it when you got prompted something depends on the implementation
a prompt upon container run, is not really advisable, as interactive container startup doesn't make sense in most cases.

However in bash you might be able to read redirect something to stdin using < 
or send it with a pipe(|) to a command.

But how to solve that issue, depends on how it is implemented in the sourcecode
where it prompts.

In general it's best practice to skip the prompt, if an env has been set.